# Bash what other type exists other than -f and -d in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to loop around a file and directories inside a bash script. I see that my code hits the else condition which is neither directory nor file. What file is it? How do I check that? Next, why is it going to else condition I am unsure. Basically, my goal is to copy the files and directories from the source to the destination. Here is the source code. I am running this inside the vscode git bash - windows.

Also, I had to do `item=$(echo $item | sed 's/[=:]//g')`  this since I was getting trailing in vscode git bash. I am unsure why do I get trailing ':'.

```
for item in $(ls src/$pre-com/* 2>/dev/null); do
        if [[ -f $item ]]; then 
            echo "$item"
            cp $item src/com1/
        elif [[ -d $item ]]; then
           echo "doing directory copy"
           item=$(echo $item | sed 's/[=:]//g') 
           echo $item
           cp -vrf $item src/com1/
        else 
            echo "Unknown type"
            
        fi
    done
```

Comment: Perhaps you could echo `$item` to find out.

Comment: Read `man test`.  The answer is -b, -c, -e, -g, -G, -h, -k, -L (same as -h), -o, -p, -r, -s, -S, -u, -w and -x.  Now ... some of those "types" are actually permission tests, but you can read all about it / them in the manual entry.

Comment: use the builtin `type $item` to see what kind of thing it is.

Comment: Also, parsing `ls` can [lead to various confusion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), so it's possible you're getting a garbled file/directory/whatever name. `ls` is for displaying files to the user, not for getting lists of names in a script.

Comment: I just googled: `if "-d" "-f" bash` and my first result was this URL, which explains the entire list of possibilities: https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html